# Exception with empty StackTrace

Tags: vb.net, exception, stack-trace

We have a method which takes care for reporting unexpected errors.

Our handling code (vb.net 4.0):

```
    Private paUnhandledException As Exception

    Private Function GetMessage(Detailed As Boolean) As String
        Dim stackMsg, msg As String
        Dim ex As Exception = Me.paUnhandledException

        If Detailed Then
            stackMsg = ex.ToString()
        ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.StackTrace)) Then
            stackMsg = ex.StackTrace
            Dim l As Integer = 0
            Try
                l = stackMsg.IndexOf(System.Environment.NewLine)
                If l > 0 Then
                    l = stackMsg.IndexOf(System.Environment.NewLine, l + 1)
                End If
                If l > 0 Then
                    l = stackMsg.IndexOf(System.Environment.NewLine, l + 1)
                End If
            Catch
                l = -1
            End Try
            If l > 0 Then
                stackMsg = stackMsg.Substring(0, l - 1)
            End If
        Else
            stackMsg = ex.ToString
        End If

        msg = String.Format("{1}{2}",ex.Message, stackMsg)
        Return msg
    End Function
```

Usually we receive reports similar to this:

> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown
>   PRINTING.INACTIVE At line 1, column 688
>
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005): Dynamic SQL
>   Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown PRINTING.INACTIVE At line
>   1, column 688 ---> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column
>   unknown PRINTING.INACTIVE At line 1, column 688    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)

We have received following report:

> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 a string constant is delimited
>   by double quotes
>
> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 a string constant is delimited
>   by double quotes

The problem - there is no stack trace.

I have did some research, read forums, stumbled upon those posts:  [exception with no stack trace - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479762/exception-with-no-stack-trace-how) and [Empty StackTrace. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530772/empty-stacktrace-possible).

Exception itself is not NULL, as we get text from `ex.Message`. If the exception was rethrown, even in this case there would be at least one row in stack trace - as of the point where it was rethrown. Similar if the exception originated in another thread. I do not think it has something to do with database system we are using - Firebird.
I have few possibilities how empty stack trace might have happened:

- OutOfMemory - program somehow went OOM, thus no stack trace
- Exception at `.toString`

So far we do not know how to simulate this error, nor have access to EventLogs from machine it originated.

Any corrections to my assumptions? What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just contact the customer and ask them to re-image the machine that has this problem.

Comment: We will give it a try, thanks.