# is stackTrace in kotlin always not empty?

Tags: kotlin, exception, stack-trace

I wonder if i call

```
println("my line: ${Throwable().stackTrace[0]}")
```

will possibly throw `IndexOutOfBoundException` caused by the empty element of `stackTrace`?

i don't know what inside of kotlin when we call `Throwable().stackTrace`

i actually could create a method helper to prevent the exception (  or simply call `stackTrace.firstOrNull()`  ), but i just curious about how kotlin do it

i've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530772/empty-stacktrace-possible) in c#, but is it relate to my question? thanks..

Comment: "i actually could create a method helper to prevent the exception" Umm, it already exists, and is called `firstOrNull`.

Comment: @Sweeper ah thanks! didn't realize that method exists

Comment: If you're targeting JVM, then there always must be a current frame (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6), so stacktrace can't be empty

Comment: @МихаилНафталь thanks, this satisfy my curiosity. feel free to answer to this post